# Eclipse debug problem - no source available

Tags: eclipse, gdb, debugging, eclipse-cdt, gdbserver

I have problem in Eclipse c/c++ with debugging. On some, not all, functions when I put break point it shows me **no sorce available** for that function ( example **no source available for test()** ). That function is static and I have source of that file in my project. What is wrong ?